# How can attacker bypass this dom xss filter?

Tags: xss, dom

I'm trying to solve an dom xss challenge where filter used is :

```
var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);
if (window.location.href.match(/(script|javascript|src|onerror|%|<|>)/g)) {
        alert('xss detected');
```

After filter is bypassed location hash is written on page through document.write.
I can't think of working solution since % is in regex , so no hex and <> is also in filter.
Any hint or suggestion in appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There's more than just normal Hex encoding! There's also Hex Entities.

`<script>alert("xss")</script>`

Is equal to:

`&#x3C;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;&#x3E;&#x61;&#x6C;&#x65;&#x72;&#x74;&#x28;&#x22;&#x78;&#x73;&#x73;&#x22;&#x29;&#x3C;&#x2F;&#x73;&#x63;&#x72;&#x69;&#x70;&#x74;&#x3E;`

There's also decimal value:
`&#60&#115&#99&#114&#105&#112&#116&#62&#97&#108&#101&#114&#116&#40&#34&#120&#115&#115&#34&#41&#60&#47&#115&#99&#114&#105&#112&#116&#62`

Hopefully this'll aid you.